# getting latitude and longitude from react-leaflet when moving the mouse

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

Is there any performant solution for getting latitude and longitude in react-leaflet when moving the mouse on the map and showing it as text below the mapContainer?
Is there any clear documentation for react-leaflet events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After receiving the map instance, you can listen to map's `mousemove` event when the component mounts. You can store then the `lat` and`lng` derived from the event and display them under the map accordingly:

```
const [coords, setCoords] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    map.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
      setCoords({ lat: e.latlng.lat, lng: e.latlng.lng });
    });
  }, [map]);
```

and then under the map

```
 {lat && (
     <div>
        <b>latitude</b>: {lat?.toFixed(4)} <br />
       <b>longitude</b>: {lng?.toFixed(4)}
    </div>
 )}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/getting-latitude-and-longitude-from-react-leaflet-v3xwhen-moving-the-mouse-peqgz?file=/src/App.js:893-1039)